# How do you understand and what is the connotation of “to dwell on a dream”

Tags: creative-writing, word-choice

I understand the phrase

> to dwell on a dream

as

> to think about that dream after waking up, maybe often or maybe sometime after I had dreamed it.

I also like the possibility that one can interpret it as if you are actually living in a dream, not in the real world.

The goal of the phrase is to be on the more poetic side too, and I am not looking just for literal interpretations only, if it evokes other interpretations or associations for you, I'd welcome them. This might eventually become a part of a title so I want to see how people understand that phrase, not just dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

There is certainly a caveat to the use of the expression 'to dwell on a dream'.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dwell-on-sth) adds part of the caveat I expected:

> **dwell on something**: to keep thinking or talking about something, *especially something bad or unpleasant*

[emphasis mine]

and while [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dwell%20on%2Fupon#:%7E:text=%3A%20to%20think%20or%20talk%20about,t%20dwell%20upon%20your%20mistakes.) doesn't actually spell this out, its first two examples show that 'dwelling on something' is often (when in the thought-life) considered a trait/practice better avoided:

> - *There is no need to dwell on the past.*
> - *Don't dwell upon your mistakes.*

Even non-negative thoughts, daydreams, are often seen as a hindrance to practical living: as a famous literary professor once said,

> - *"It does not do to dwell on dreams and forget to live."*

[[HarryPotter Fandom](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Mirror_of_Erised#:%7E:text=%22Albus%20Dumbledore%27s%20words%20of%20caution,becomes%20unhelpful%20and%20even%20unhealthy.)]. I've added this particular source for the Dumbledore quote as the article contains much more, helpful, analysis of / opinion about *dwelling on dreams*.

Answer (score 1):

When I "dwell" on a dream, I try to remember as much as possible before all memory of it fades. The main reason I do it is to see if there is anything I can take from it to write about. The second reason is to figure out if it has any meaning to my life.